# Mathematica, modifying list of transitions

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica

The reason why Google didn't provide me the answer is I don't know the right name of the list elements in this case (*). Here I have some input data:

```
edges = ReadList["some\\external\\data\\source\\1"]
 (* edges = { 0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3 } *)

labels = ReadList["some\\external\\data\\source\\2"]
 (* labels = { 0 -> A, 1 -> B, 2 -> A, 3 -> B } *)
```

I want to create a new list **styles** from **labels** with replaced **A** to **Red** and **B** to **Green** so I can get:

```
styles = { 0 -> Red, 1 -> Green, 2 -> Red, 3 -> Green }
```

I'm using it for drawing a graph:

```
Graph [ edges, VertexLabels -> labels, VertexStyle -> styles ]
```

(*) tried list of pairs, list of transitions, list of edges, but found that RightArrow operator has a general meaning...

Comment: Sorry, you say that right arrow has a general meaning, but it's not clear to me what you mean by it.

Comment: I mean by this that I can't find whether A -> B is a relation, assignment, hierarchy or transition?

Comment: @Bartek The `FullForm` of `A->B` is `Rule[A,B]`.  In other words, it is a transformation rule. This has a well-defined meaning in Mathematica. See http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitionsOverview.html

Comment: @David Thanks for the information. However, based on http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingSetsOfTransformationRules.html I wouldn't be able to solve this problem on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
edges = {0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}

labels = {0 -> A, 1 -> B, 2 -> A, 3 -> B}
styles = labels /. {A -> Red, B -> Green}
Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> labels, VertexStyle -> styles]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about starting with a "database":

```
edges[0] = 1; edges[1] = 2; edges[2] = 3;
labels[0] = "A"; labels[1] = "B"; labels[2] = "A"; labels[3] = "B";
```

and then some replacement rules:

```
s["A"] = "Red"; s["B"] = "Green";
```

which lets your define your new `labels` function:

```
styles[e_] := s[labels[e]]
```

which gives

```
In[9]:= Table[styles[i], {i, 0, 3}]

Out[9]= {"Red", "Green", "Red", "Green"}
```

etc...

Comment: I'm reading an external data:

edges = ReadList["\\Workspace\\data\\graph\\1.edg"];
labels = ReadList["\\Workspace\\data\\graph\\1.lab"];

and I need an efficient solution.

Comment: Also I don't know how to convert between a "database" approach and the graph data.